# Windows phone 8.1 HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, httpwebrequest

I have some problems implementing HttpWebRequest in my Windows phone app.

It's the first time I work on this class and I don't get how to implement methods:

This is my request:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fullPath) as HttpWebRequest;
```

My aim is to return 2 values: a ref string wich is the name of the file downloaded(It is NOT same as the file name passed to URL, because the title is my sha256 code.) and the JsonTextReader of the content of file downloaded.

This is how I need to conclude the method:

```
shaDownloaded = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", String.Empty).Replace("\"", String.Empty);
reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
JsonTextReader jReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
return jReader;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to reach this point. I tryed some ways but i always had the download going async with the stackTrace, so always null response. Anyone can help implementing a good Method? this is my portion of code:

```
public JsonTextReader DownloadFileFromService(string fileUrl, string fileName, string oldSha, ref string newSha)
    {
        try
        {
            string fullPath = string.Format(fileUrl + fileName + "&sha=" + oldSha);
            StreamReader reader;

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fullPath) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Get response here {

                shaDownloaded = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", String.Empty).Replace("\"", String.Empty);

                reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            //}

            JsonTextReader jReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
            return jReader;

        } catch(Exception ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I can't really solve this. Thanks in advice for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm I don't know If I understood what's your problem but I try to answer

It's how I use HttpWebRequest, try to implement it.

```
public async Task<object []> ApiCommand(string api, string json)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Variables.apiURL + api);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(Variables.apiURL + api, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            return new[] {response.StatusCode.ToString(), await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()};
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new[] {"EXCEPTION", ex.ToString()};
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I probably badly explained.. my only problem here is with the httpclient, wich is not implemented on windows phone :(

Comment: It's implemented because I use it in my project just add dll

Comment: Ok, i had to implement it a lot but it worked perfectly! thanks a lot :)